# How to merge lists of objects based on their id's using the spread operator (ES6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

say i have two lists of objects,

```
list1 = [{id: 1, name: "tom", age:25}, {id: 2, name: "brad", age:35}, {id: 3, name: "marry", age:23}]
```

and

```
list2 = [{id: 1, OS: "Windows"}, {id: 2, OS: "Mac"}];
```

how do I obtain

```
finalList = [{id: 1, name: "tom", age:25, OS: "Windows"}, {id: 2, name: "brad", age:35, OS: "Mac"}, {id: 3, name: "marry", age:23}
```

I would like to achieve this with the spread operator if at all possible, handling the scenarios where the lists are of different lenghts, and some objects dont hav id's.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return new result based on `list1` and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get corresponding element from `list2` for `list1` item:

```js
let list1 = [{id: 1, name: "tom", age:25}, {id: 2, name: "brad", age:35}, {id: 3, name: "marry", age:23}];

let list2 = [{id: 1, OS: "Windows"}, {id: 2, OS: "Mac"}];

let result = list1.map(x => {
    let l2 = list2.find(y => y.id === x.id);
    return l2 ? { ...x, ...l2 } : x;
  });
  
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will merge object of any length and any number of arguments

```js
function merge(...args) {
    const max_pointer = Math.max(...args.map(arg=>arg.length));
    const test = []
    for (let i = 0; i < max_pointer; i++) {
        let e = args.map(arg=>arg[i]);
        let new_obj = Object.assign({}, ...e);
        test.push(new_obj);
    }
    return test;
}

const list1 = [{id: 1, name: "tom", age:25}, {id: 2, name: "brad", age:35}, {id: 3, name: "marry", age:23}] 
const list2 = [{id: 1, OS: "Windows"}, {id: 2, OS: "Mac"}]; 



console.log(merge(list1, list2));
```